# SharePoint Library ribbon IE disappears when clicked on Library in the ribbon.

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am facing an issue on IE for all the SharePoint libraries. When i hover over to library tab in the ribbon, it shows the ribbon and disappears in a blink of an eye. The site is added to the trusted sites, i also added it to the Compatibility view and still the issue persists.

Below is the version info for IE. Also this appears to occur on Windows 7 and 10 so far.

[image]

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually noticed a weird solution to this approach. I had a custom JS Code applied at the Master page level to show site name on a document library page and also for displaying all the views without having to click on the three dots to access a view. This was rendering fine in Mozilla and chrome but IE had issues. So once I took off the code from master page, the issue got resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does this issue happen on all libraries? Or just one library? Are you using IE 32-bit? Try to use IE 32-bit.

You can try below things:

1. Try to clean the browser cache.
2. Try to click one of your documents, then check if the ribbon display.
3. Try to click F12 in IE, change mode to IE 10, then check the results.

If above methods do not work, refer to below article for more solutions:

https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/missing-ribbon-in-sharepoint-online-or-sharepoint-on-premises-list/